# Control decimal output to csv from skimr output

Tags: r, export-to-csv, skimr

I can control the decimals in the output of skimr in this way:

```
library(skimr)
options(pillar.sigfig = 2)
skim(faithful)
```

but I need to be able to output the results to a csv file. Doing this, the decimals are not affected.
How can I modify the decimal output of tibbles for export to a csv?

```
options(pillar.sigfig = 2)
skim(faithful)%>%
write.csv("~/test.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`skimr::skim()` uses the pillar package to print the underlying `skim_df` object in the console. If you write the `skim_df` to a csv file, printing options are not considered.

You can treat the `skim_df` like a `tibble` or `data.frame`. The code below shortens the decimals to 2 for all numeric columns in the `skim_df` object.

```
library(skimr)
library(dplyr)
skim(faithful) |> 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 2)) |> 
  write.csv("test.csv")
```